# What is charged particle multiplicity density?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology

In the [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider), hadrons are collided with one another and studied. At various instances, e.g. [ALICE](http://aliceinfo.cern.ch/Public/Welcome.html) papers I come across this "**charged particle multiplicity density**." What exactly is this? I have searched so many forums. Nowhere is this answered. It would be awesome if anybody could give some basics for understanding this concept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiplicity is a fancy way of saying "number of".

e.g. track multiplicity is just the number of tracks in an event.

Density will imply that this is normalised to a unit value of some quantity like volume/angle/solid-angle.